# skimage io.ImageCollection not showing all files I want when using io.ImageCollection to add multiple types of files to show

Tags: python, scikit-image

Using this code:

```
ic = io.ImageCollection('../images/*.png')
​
print('Type:', type(ic))
​
ic.files
```

i get this:

```
Type: <class 'skimage.io.collection.ImageCollection'>
['../images\\chapel_floor.png',
 '../images\\clock_motion.png',
 '../images\\cycle_spin.png',
 '../images\\fingers.png',
 '../images\\mpl_hist.png',
 '../images\\snakes.png',
 '../images\\zebrafish-spinal-cord-color.png',
 '../images\\zebrafish-spinal-cord.png']
```

Using this code:

```
ic = io.ImageCollection('../images/*.png:../images/*.jpg')

print('Type:', type(ic))

ic.files
```

i get this:

```
> Type: <class 'skimage.io.collection.ImageCollection'
> []
```

when I try just one type of search for specific file, I get a view of all the files, but when I try to do the multiple thing by adding the ':' in between, which is the way its suppose to be i get nothing.

Comment: The documentation says: Multiple patterns should be separated by os.pathsep. So try: `import os; print(os.pathsep)`, on Windows I get ";"

Comment: See also https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/3258 ; we are going to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

change the : to ;
ic = io.ImageCollection('../images/*.png;../images/*.jpg')

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use : on Mac and Linux and ; on windows to separate *.png and *.jpg